# Oracle sql functions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table with a column called `Type`, which can have three values (`name1`, `name2`, `name3`).

Can I write a query which first returns the records with `Type` = `name1` and then the rows with values `name2` and `name3` with a `WHERE` clause, so I can filter them by `CreationDate` for instance?

That means, return for day `01/01/2000`:

```
row  'name1'
row  'name1'
(rest of the rows)
```

```
Id   Type    CreationDate  
1,  'name1', '2000/01/01'  
8,  'name1', '2000/01/01'  
18, 'name3', '2000/01/01'  
82, 'name2', '2000/01/01'  
11, 'name2', '2000/01/01'  
12, 'name3', '2000/01/01'  
2,  'name1', '2000/01/02'  
4,  'name1', '2000/01/02'  
98, 'name2', '2000/01/02'
```

For every day, get records of type 'name1' first and then the rest of the types with just no order.

Thank you! Udo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can order by create date then type.  If you need to define the order of the type you can use a case.

```
SELECT id, Type, CreationDate
FROM  "table"
ORDER BY CreationDate ASC,
         CASE WHEN Type = 'name1' THEN 1
              ELSE 2
         END ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

PMV's answer above should work fine  Putting this in just as an alternate option.

```
SELECT id, Type, CreationDate
FROM  "table" 
ORDER BY CreationDate, decode(Type , 'name1', 0, 1), Type ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to prioritize the ordering only based on Date and type='name1' and specifically need the remaining order to be random in nature.  If this is the case you can add dbms_random.value as the third item in the ORDER BY in either PMV or Insane's query.  Sample table and example follow:

```
create table Table1 (Id Number(2), Type Varchar2(5), CreationDate Date);
insert into Table1 Values ( 1,'name1',to_date('01/01/2000','MM/DD/YYYY'));
insert into Table1 Values ( 8,'name1',to_date('01/01/2000','MM/DD/YYYY'));
insert into Table1 Values (18,'name3',to_date('01/01/2000','MM/DD/YYYY'));
insert into Table1 Values (82,'name2',to_date('01/01/2000','MM/DD/YYYY'));
insert into Table1 Values (11,'name2',to_date('01/01/2000','MM/DD/YYYY'));
insert into Table1 Values (12,'name3',to_date('01/01/2000','MM/DD/YYYY'));
insert into Table1 Values ( 2,'name1',to_date('01/02/2000','MM/DD/YYYY'));
insert into Table1 Values ( 4,'name1',to_date('01/02/2000','MM/DD/YYYY'));
insert into Table1 Values (98,'name2',to_date('01/02/2000','MM/DD/YYYY'));

SELECT Id, Type, CreationDate FROM Table1
ORDER BY CreationDate, decode(Type , 'name1', 0, 1) ASC, dbms_random.value;
```